# Why when I include a llama_index module do I get pydantic validation errors with FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, llama-index

The following code works fine, however as soon as I remove the comment from the first line, I get a validation error from Pydantic:

```
File "main.py", line 341, in __init__ raise validation_error pydantic.v1.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for DataSource
component_type subclass of BaseComponent expected (type=type_error.subclass; expected_class=BaseComponent)
```

This is the code with the first line commented out.

```
#from llama_index.core import Document

from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/files/")
def create_file(file: Annotated[bytes, File()]):
    return {"file_size": len(file),
            "content": file}
```

It seems no matter which llama_index module I import, I get the same error.  If there is no llama_index module imported then there is no error.  The issue is that I need to use llama_index for this.

Comment: Maybe you have version of Pydantic that is not compatible with `llama_index`?

Comment: That is not the issue, I rolled back to 1.10 and I still get the issue and 1.10 should be a compatible version.

Comment: I face the same issue and can't figure it out...

Comment: I had similar issue and ending up deleting my venv and re-pip installing everything, then it started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from llama_index import Document
```